# How to transform a line into a curve with the mouse in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt4

I am having trouble with a project of mine. I am trying to draw in an render-area a course for the cars (a street) which can contain both straight lines and curves. For that I was thinking of primarily drawing the lines and then with the mouse selecting one line and transforming it into a curve by moving the mouse (a curve which has as peek the point on the line selected by the mouse). Until now I only managed to draw points in the render area and automatically generate lines between these points, but I am not sure about how to transform the line into a curve with the mouse.

My code until now is:

renderarea.cpp:

```
RenderArea::RenderArea(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
}
void RenderArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    point = e->pos();
    updateList(point);
    this->update();
}
void RenderArea::updateList(const QPoint& p)
{
    Point point;
    point.point = p;
    list.append(point);
    if (list.count()>1)
        lineAdded(point);
}
void RenderArea::lineAdded(const Point &p)
{
    Line temp;
    temp.endPoint = p;
    temp.startPoint = list.at(list.count() - 2);
    lines.append(temp);
}
void RenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    int i;
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,2));
    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        painter.drawPoint(list[i].point);
    for (i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
        painter.drawLine(lines[i].startPoint.point, lines[i].endPoint.point);
}
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have some UI (right click?) that changes the line segment to Besier curve. Then control the shape of the curve by dragging handles (which **you** will need to provide). Another right click changes the curve back to segment.

Comment: But how can I select the segment with the mouse? Is there any special method for detecting it on my render area?

Comment: Treat the line segment as a bounding box.  If the mouse coordinate is within the bounding box, the segment is selected.  This allows for magnification of a line into a rectangle.  You may also want to give the User some slack, and say +- 5 pixels from the outer line.

Comment: Alternatively, compute the distance of mouse pointer from line segment - look up the math on the web. Take a look here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969920.aspx) among other places. (I assume QT has some equivalent of GetPath from Win32 API).